# How do I change the white text in vs code for vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having problem with this. It was working fine for the first hour after i installed but the code text suddenly turned white, i tried restarting my computer and i have the extension installed but it's still not working. Also, it's working fine for other languages such as C and javascript.

```js
const app = new Vue {(
  el:'app',
  data:  {
    username:'troller'
  }
})
```

[image: Sample screenshot]

Comment: We cannot debug code in images. Please remove them and edit the question to include a text-based [mcve]

Comment: Please post code, not a picture of code - by the way, there's now white text in that pretty picture - `i have the extension installed` ... what extension?

Comment: note: javascript in a `.vue` SFC file MUST be inside `<script>` tag - the editor thinks (and it's right) that is the HTML - though even then, HTML in `.vue` SFC file MUST be inside a `<template>` tag

Comment: @JaromandaX here, OP is using the CDN probably so no, the code itself doesn't need to be as in a SFC file. Also, not every JS code needs to be in a `script` section even in an SFC, you can totally write some helpers/generic functions outside and call them inside of `script`.

Comment: @kissu - the file is `ca.vue` ... `.vue` files are vue SFC's ... so, not sure what `vuejs` you use ... also, in an SFC, you CAN write code in the markup, but you can't create "helpers/generic functions and call them" outside of a script tag -

Comment: @JaromandaX there was no screenshot posted when I commented. EDIT: you removed it before I came to this question, not sure why.  Also, not sure what OP did here but there is definitely a mix between several things. Still, the build step is not on point for sure. For the last part, totally feasible tho: vanilla JS still exists.

Comment: **I removed nothing** @kissu - the screenshot was just a link, not embeded as SOMEONE ELSE did - all I did was fix the text so it wasn't a link to the image when there was already a separate link to the image - and yes, vanilla JS exists, but inside a .vue file it needs to be inside a `<script>` tag